# 7zip E_FAIL Error

Tags: server, backup, 7zip

I've done a Backup some time ago using 7zip, in which I splited the Files in 14 2GB (aprox) files. I'm running Ubuntu Server 15.10.

This is what I'm trying to run in order to extract them:

```
7z x Backup.7z.001
```

Just in case I've also tried (although I don't get the difference between 'x' and 'e'):

```
7z e Backup.7z.001
```

And this is what I get:

> 7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
>
> p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)
>
> Processing archive: Backup.7z.001
>
> Error: E_FAIL

I've been doing some research and it seems "E_FAIL" error means "lack of disk space". However, I have plenty of diskspace, this is what I get when I run  "df -h"

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

udev                     791M     0  791M   0% /dev

tmpfs                    161M  5,6M  156M   4% /run

/dev/sda2                450G   73G  354G  18% /

tmpfs                    805M  4,0K  805M   1% /dev/shm

tmpfs                    5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock

tmpfs                    805M     0  805M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

tmpfs                    161M     0  161M   0% /run/user/1000


/home/cristian/.Private  450G   73G  354G  18% /home/cristian
```

If you require any more information, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: where are you trying to extract to - your `home`?

Comment: @Ron I've tried in /srv/Samba/photos, then I've tried in /home/cristian/Test just in case but still nothing.